# Creating an Array of Variable-Dimensional Arrays

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am trying to create a `float` array `I` such that it's elements house arrays of 2, 3, 4, and 5 dimensions:

```
I: [0][1052] [1052]
   [1][N]    [185]  [185]
   [2][N]    [N]    [34]  [34]
   [3][N]    [N]    [N]   [6]  [6]
```

Where `N` is some constant I haven't decided yet. For example, `I[0]` references a `float[][]` but `I[1]` references a `float[][][]`.

This is supposed to be a hierarchy of data squares which are related to each other. In other words, this is like a file system where each folder conatins `N` more child folders.

Is there a way that I can accomplish this besides declaring `I` with 6 dimensions or using 4 separate arrays?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An array is an object. So you can create an Object array, and store 1D or 2D or 100D arrays in it:

```
Object[] arr = new Object[3];
arr[0] = new float[][]{}; //2D
arr[1] = new float[][][][]{}; //4D
arr[2] = new float[]{}; //1D
```

The downside is that it won't stop you from storing non-float multi dimensional arrays:

```
arr[0] = new String[][]{};
arr[1] = new Object[]{};
arr[2] = new Integer[][][]{};
```

Comment: What does the `{}` after the `[]` do?

Comment: @Petersen just initializing the array with nothing. But you won't need it as you already have those arrays.

Answer (score 0):

NOTE: It's not a good way to deal with arrays, specially multi-dimensional array. Anyways, if you do it this way,

```
Object[] I = new Object[4];
```

Then you can do this,

```
I[0] = new float[2];
I[1] = new float[3];
I[2] = new float[4];
I[3] = new float[5];
```